# Embedding an entity refenrence add button on a q=node/view page

Tags: forms, nodes, entities

I am creating a '*Activity Management*' site for that I have created **Activity** and **Participant** content types.

**Participant** content type has *Full Name, Cell No, Email, Address fields* and '**Activity**' has *title, location, time* and *activity participant* - entity reference field of **Participant** content type.

I have created 'activity managers' role who can add/delete participant of an activity. I want to add two buttons on activity q=node/(view/display) page from where 'activity managers' can

1. Add new participant
2. Add from existing participant, to the activity.

I have played around inline entity form, entity form but without luck. Inline entity form does it but on node/(add/edit) page not from `q=node/view`.